White plant (black berry)
I ordered a bare root blackberry plant on eBay and it took about a week to get to my house when I opened up the baggie it was in with the soil the whole plant is white I'm not sure if it's a blackberry plant or not?

A picture would be useful.  It sounds like it has been deprived of light for a while - which is why its white - no chlorophyll production.  I hope it survives if you want it to (they are weeds here, and I hate the things personally) - but I would not give it great odds.

Or it's got white mold all over it. In either case, put the roots in dirt and get the plant into the sun. And [edit] in a picture. Odd for a bare root plant to come with soil - but I suppose sketchy ebay sellers who are not actual plant nurseries might  fail to follow proper phytosanitation procedures.
